# How do I extract the following information using PHP Regex / preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following HTML and I need to extract the URL inside VALUE

```
<param name="movie" value="http://domain.com/path/to/file.swf" />
```

I tried the following, with no success.

```
preg_match("'<param name=\"movie\" value=\"(.*?)\" />si'", $source,  $url); 
echo $url[1];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML, use [DOM Document](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Guess what will happen if your markup code starts looking like this `<param value ="something" name="movie" />`. If you need a regex to solve a markup problem then you have at least two problems.

Comment: I am clueless, what will happen? Is this piece of code not properly coded? I am confused.

Comment: More information on why not to use a regex for this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My, correct variant:

```
$source = '<param name="movie" value="http://domain.com/path/to/file.swf" />';

preg_match('!<param name="movie" value="(.*?)"!U', $source,  $url); 
echo $url[1];
```

The result:

```
http://domain.com/path/to/file.swf
```

Note the modifier `U` which means `Ungreedy`, it allows `.*` to be compact and not return more than we actually need.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `preg_match` you can do:

```
preg_match('/<param name=\"movie\" value=\"(.*?)\" \/>/is', $source, $url);
echo $url[1]
```

Problem was with not escaping a `/` symbol at the end of a tag and you have `"` and `'` next to each other without a reason probably.

Comment: You can use other delimiters than `/`. And the original code attempted to use `'` single quotes, which would be fine, if the regex `is` flags had been moved **after** *↓ :)* the ending `'` delimiter.

Comment: @mario Maybe, but it would be better if they were **after** the ending delimiter. ;)